# Error messages don't work with a render block

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

In my template.php file, I added

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
   $block = block_load('my_module','my_delta');
   $render_array = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
   $vars['my_output'] = drupal_render($render_array);
}
```

In my custom-node.php file, I added

```
<?php print $my_output; ?>
```

My block is already displaying but the problem is:

My block contains a form with required fields, if I submit with an empty required field, the error messages are not displaying.

Any idea please?

Thank you